# ObservableCollection.Contains() Doesn't Work Correctly

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net

Consider the following:

```
class Bind
{
    public string x { get; set; }
    public string y { get; set; }
}
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ObservableCollection<Bind> cX = new ObservableCollection<Bind>();
        ObservableCollection<Bind> cY = new ObservableCollection<Bind>();
        cX.Add(new Bind { x = "a", y = "1" });
        cX.Add(new Bind { x = "b", y = "2" });
        cY.Add(new Bind { x = "a", y = "1" });
        foreach (var i in cX)
        {
            if (!cY.Contains(i)) { lv.Items.Add(i); } //lv is a ListView control
        }
    }
}
```

Why does it add  `x = "a", y = "1"` to the `ListView`?

If I change `ObservableCollection` to `List` or `Collection`, it does the same.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The 'Contains' method uses the Equals on object, and this simply checks that the memory addresses are different.

Consider changing your class to this...

```
 class Bind : IEquatable<Bind> {
     public string x { get; set; }
     public string y { get; set; }
     public bool Equals(Bind other)
     {
         return x == other.x && y == other.y; 
     } 
}
```

Your loop will then visit the strongly typed Equals method in your class, and this will result in the behaviour you are after.

NOTE:  the string class ALSO inherits from IEquatable of T and that is what allows the equality operator to operate on the content of the string rather than the address of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Because that you have added that value set to CX:

```
cX.Add(new Bind { x = "a", y = "1" });
```

and to CY:

```
cY.Add(new Bind { x = "a", y = "1" });
```

And those are different objects.

If you want to see if a given key is present, you will need to change to a dictionary or use Linq.

Answer (score 1):

Because `"a" != "a"`. At least, not always.

`Contains()` will check memory addresses, not the actual contents. You cannot insert the same object twice, and `"a"` isn't the same object as `"a"` (at least, not here).

Comment: I'd probably iterate through all values and check whether they are equal. But I'm not a C# programmer, so there might be an easier way.

Answer (score 1):

You should inform about comparer:

["Elements are compared to the specified value by using the default equality comparer, Default."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880.aspx)

In [EqualityComparer.Default Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx) you can see an example.