# Why do I get different object form same source by different way?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I create a static class that includes the definition of global variables and functions, but maybe it is wrong.

I need to crete a shopping cart, after refreshing,the content shouldn't be lost.

In staic class A, I create a staic variables ObservableCollection Collection1 and Collection2(Collection1 have children but Collection2) and staic functions Refresh() used to refresh Collection1.

In dynamic class B, I get some children and add them to Collection2, then use A.Refresh(), in the process of refreshing, if the new data have same id as any one in old Collection2, add it in new Collection2.

```cs
public class Model
{
        public Guid Id{ get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }
}

public static class A
{
        public static ObservableCollection<Model> Collection1 { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Model>();

        public static ObservableCollection<Model> Collection2 { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Model>();


        public static Refresh()
        {
            var uidList = Collection2.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
            Collection1.Clear();
            Collection2.Clear();
            foreach (var item in dataFromServer)
            {
                var newModel = new Model{Id = item.Id};
                Collection1.Add(newModel);
                if(uidList.Contains(item.Id))
                {
                    Collection2.Add(newModel);
                }
            }
        }
}

public class B
{
        public B()
        {
            A.Refresh();
        }

        public AddToCart(Guid id)
        {
            var model = A.Collection1.First(x=>x.Id == id);
            if (!A.Collection2.Contains(model))
            {
                A.Collection2.Add(model);
            }
        }

        public Refresh()
        {
            A.Refresh();
        }
}
```

I used B.AddToCart(AAAA) to add a child to Collection2,then used B.Refresh(),now I have new data form server,a new object(Id is AAAA) in Collection1 and Collection2.Then I used B.AddToCart(AAAA) again,now Collection2 have two children with same Id and Name,even I change one of the,the other one's name changed too.It's meaning there are same two object in Collection2 right?But why does A.Collection2.Contains(model) return false?I used Object.ReferenceEquals to check the two children,the result is false,too.
I konw Collection2.Any(x=>x.Id==id) can be worked,I just want to konw how it happened.

Edit:I create a demo,but he problem did not recur,maybe something wrong in other part.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `IEquatable<Model>` on your `Model` class.

This is a duplicate question, REF: [ObservableCollection.Contains() Doesn't Work Correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690280/observablecollection-contains-doesnt-work-correctly)

Comment: That does not explain why `object.ReferenceEquals` fails.

Comment: During the refreshing,children of Collection1 and Collection2 are refreshed in same time.

Comment: I create a demo,but he problem did not recur,maybe something wrong in other part.Thank you anyway.

Comment: @SebastianSchumann The code in the question does not correlate with the text of the question. How can Collection1 and Collection2 contain Model items with the same names (other than null) when their Name is never set by `var newModel = new Model{Id = item.Id};`?

Comment: @SebastianSchumann If I were a betting person I'd wager that the problem with the real code that's not being shown occurs with `if (!A.Collection2.Contains(model))` in AddToCart. Specifically, the line before is probably doing `.Select(x => new Model{...})` shenanigans, which will return a different object instance than what's actually in Collection2 and so always fails the test. Given the example code I'm left wondering why Collection2 isn't an `ObservableCollection<Guid>` or `List<Guid>` - at least `Guid` is `IEquatable`. There's more going on than what's shown in the OP's example.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning You are right.These codes are used in a wpf program,in reality,the variable `model` in `AddToCart` is not found by `Model.Id` from `Collection1`,the context of `Collection1` is passed to a new `ObservableCollection` with filter in class `B`,then I found a child in new collection by `Id`,this child is the truly `model` in `AddToCart`.But I suggest it's  equivalent to my example.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I used global search and found `new Model` is used in `A.Refresh` only.Maybe something wrong in parameter passing.If I used some code like `.Select(x => new Model{...})`,I don't think it can be worked before refresh second time.